# Get cumulative sum on column category in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe where the index is usergroup1_ids and column names are usergroup2_ids. The values of the dataframe are similarities between users from respective groups. For eg.

```
temp_sim_matrix = pd.DataFrame(data = np.random.rand(2,3), columns = ['1', '2', '3'])
print(temp_sim_matrix)

          0         1         2
0  0.982759  0.993010  0.957348
1  0.896425  0.552502  0.455066
```

Now the column names are related to a category based on a list where the column names are the indexes for the list:

```
column_category = ["A", "B", "A"]
```

I want to generate a dictionary that gives me the cumulative for each category for each index value in the dataframe. Like this:

```
{0: Counter({'A': 1.9401077624739544,
             'B': 0.9930103537159203}),
 1: Counter({'A': 1.3514912433327915,
             'B': 0.5525021211525775})}
```

Is there an efficient pythonic way of doing this because I am currently doing it by iterating over each row in the dataframe then putting cumulative values in a Counter. Maybe I am missing some function from pandas that can be used here. My implementation is:

```
row_index_dict = {} # Initializing final dictionary

for index, row in temp_sim_matrix.iterrows(): # Iterating over each row
  cat_counter = Counter() # Creating counter to store cumulative value

  for i in range(len(column_category)): # Loop over columns
    cat_counter[column_category[i]] += row[i] #Add value of row to respective counter key

  row_index_dict[index] = cat_counter #Adding counter to final dictionary
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you can aggregate `sum` with list `column_category`, because same length like columns names and then convert it to dictionary by[`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) :

```
column_category = ["A", "B", "A"]

d = df.groupby(column_category, axis=1).sum().to_dict('index')
print (d)
{0: {'A': 1.940107, 'B': 0.9930100000000001}, 1: {'A': 1.351491, 'B': 0.552502}}
```

If need `Counter` use:

```
d1 = {k: Counter(v) for k, v in d.items()}
```

Comment: This works perfectly! I'll put the nested dictionary in a Counter so that I can use the most_common() function. Thank you so much!

Comment: @specinthedark - Ya, also added to answer.